Deployment timeout on Azure Web app Linux
I'm deploying my React+Node app to the Azure App service. The build stage is fine but the deploy stage fails with The job running on runner GitHub Actions 10 has exceeded the maximum execution time of 360 minutes.
The log says Package deployment using OneDeploy initiated. and then it starts polling and times out after 6 hours
##[debug]setting affinity cookie ["ARRAffinity=f07aec79734d8bf10f3fd4121c637821b5012b69243d980eeadb0c647194e673;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=engrant-app.scm.azurewebsites.net","ARRAffinitySameSite=f07aec79734d8bf10f3fd4121c637821b5012b69243d980eeadb0c647194e673;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=engrant-app.scm.azurewebsites.net"]
##[debug][POST] https://engrant-app.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/publish?async=true&deployer=GITHUB_ONE_DEPLOY&type=zip&message=%7B%22type%22%3A%22deployment%22%2C%22sha%22%3A%226c41ed25e1ac09c9b937aced42e0af8f031ef47f%22%2C%22repoName%22%3A%22uluhonolulu%2Fengrant-app%22%2C%22actor%22%3A%22uluhonolulu%22%2C%22slotName%22%3A%22Production%22%2C%22commitMessage%22%3A%22Vector%20search%20for%20islaidos%22%7D
##[debug]One Deploy response: {"statusCode":202,"statusMessage":"Accepted","headers":{"content-length":"0","date":"Sun, 15 Dec 2024 07:18:46 GMT","server":"Kestrel","location":"https://engrant-app.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/api/deployments/latest?deployer=OneDeploy&time=2024-12-15_07-18-46Z","scm-deployment-id":"d88280a8-0734-4be6-8547-8a954b286479","retryafter":"30"},"body":""}
##[debug]Polling for One Deploy URL: https://engrant-app.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/api/deployments/latest?deployer=OneDeploy&time=2024-12-15_07-18-46Z

How do I fix it?
Update: here's the job file from GitHub. The timeout occurs on the last step.
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write #This is required for requesting the JWT

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip
      
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_151B8A5FF05243BFBA066202A96501B1 }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_087D3248B87541B08EBA7B811E3789BC }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_0DD026630EFD48A5B5A3C170971C85F1 }}

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        with:
          app-name: 'engrant-app'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .
    ```


We don't know your deploy scripts. You have to review them to figure out what fails to run in the alloted time.

No scripts, I'm just using the default job from GitHub -- updated the question

Jobs are scripts...

Fixed it by setting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE to 1, but I'd still appreciate it if someone could explain to me why a standard deployment with the default setup would timeout after 6 hours.
